# Recursion in Java Dealing with Diamonds

Tags: java, recursion

I've come up with a code that displays a diamond pattern from a certain file within the computer. The problem that I'm having is that there are different ints that the code reads and every * on the first line is off. I'm really not sure how to fix this problem because the first diamond shows up perfect. Also I'm having trouble with my if statement as well. If the number is less than 0 or greater than 25 it shouldn't print out, but even with the if statement I have the diamond is still printing out. Can anyone help me with these two problems?

CODE

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Pract2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File("prog3.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    new Pract2().results(num);
    if (num < 0)
      System.out.println("Cannot Print");
    if (num > 25)
      System.out.println("Cannot Print");
    } 
  }

  public String method1 (int num) {
    if (num > 0){
      return "* " + method1(num - 1);
    }
    else {
      return " ";
    }
  }

  public String method2 (int num) {
    if (num > 0) {
      return " * " + method1(num -1);
    }
    else {
      return " ";
    }
  }
  public String space (int num) {
    if (num > 0) {
      return " " + space(num - 1);
    }
    else {
      return " ";
    }
  }
  public void results (int num) {
    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
      System.out.print(space(num - i));
      System.out.println(method1(i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      System.out.println(method2(num-i));
      System.out.print(space(i));
    }
  }
}
```

output:

```
    *  
   * *  
  * * *  
 * * * *  
  * * *  
   * *  
    *  
       *  
  * *  
 * * *  
  * *  
   *  
                  *  
              * *  
             * * *  
            * * * *  
           * * * * *  
          * * * * * *  
         * * * * * * *  
        * * * * * * * *  
       * * * * * * * * *  
      * * * * * * * * * *  
     * * * * * * * * * * *  
    * * * * * * * * * * * *  
   * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
  * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
  * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
   * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
    * * * * * * * * * * * *  
     * * * * * * * * * * *  
      * * * * * * * * * *  
       * * * * * * * * *  
        * * * * * * * *  
         * * * * * * *  
          * * * * * *  
           * * * * *  
            * * * *  
             * * *  
              * *  
               *  
                                         *  
                         * *  
                        * * *  
                       * * * *  
                      * * * * *  
                     * * * * * *  
                    * * * * * * *  
                   * * * * * * * *  
                  * * * * * * * * *  
                 * * * * * * * * * *  
                * * * * * * * * * * *  
               * * * * * * * * * * * *  
              * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
             * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
            * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
           * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
          * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
         * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
        * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
       * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
      * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
     * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
     * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
      * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
       * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
        * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
         * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
          * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
           * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
            * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
             * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
              * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
               * * * * * * * * * * * *  
                * * * * * * * * * * *  
                 * * * * * * * * * *  
                  * * * * * * * * *  
                   * * * * * * * *  
                    * * * * * * *  
                     * * * * * *  
                      * * * * *  
                       * * * *  
                        * * *  
                         * *  
                          *  
                          Cannot Print
```

> 

expect output:

```
    *  
   * *  
  * * *  
 * * * *  
  * * *  
   * *  
    *

   *  
  * *  
 * * *  
  * *  
   *  
               *  
              * *  
             * * *  
            * * * *  
           * * * * *  
          * * * * * *  
         * * * * * * *  
        * * * * * * * *  
       * * * * * * * * *  
      * * * * * * * * * *  
     * * * * * * * * * * *  
    * * * * * * * * * * * *  
   * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
  * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
  * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
   * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
    * * * * * * * * * * * *  
     * * * * * * * * * * *  
      * * * * * * * * * *  
       * * * * * * * * *  
        * * * * * * * *  
         * * * * * * *  
          * * * * * *  
           * * * * *  
            * * * *  
             * * *  
              * *  
               *  
                          *  
                         * *  
                        * * *  
                       * * * *  
                      * * * * *  
                     * * * * * *  
                    * * * * * * *  
                   * * * * * * * *  
                  * * * * * * * * *  
                 * * * * * * * * * *  
                * * * * * * * * * * *  
               * * * * * * * * * * * *  
              * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
             * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
            * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
           * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
          * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
         * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
        * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
       * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
      * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
     * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
     * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
      * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
       * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
        * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
         * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
          * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
           * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
            * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
             * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
              * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
               * * * * * * * * * * * *  
                * * * * * * * * * * *  
                 * * * * * * * * * *  
                  * * * * * * * * *  
                   * * * * * * * *  
                    * * * * * * *  
                     * * * * * *  
                      * * * * *  
                       * * * *  
                        * * *  
                         * *  
                          *
```

> 

Comment: The `if` statement occurs after the line that causes the results to be printed. The call to `results` is not conditional on the `if` at all.

Comment: replace all your spaces(" ") with ".", you will something interesting

Comment: David before it showed that your comment stated that there was no recursion...Is this true? I'm a beginner at recursion so I know how it works. I just assumed that this was recursion

Comment: I see that each method calls on itself...I thought that was recursion

Comment: @user3846760 yes there is recursion in `method1` and `space`. Dont know what people are talking about "no recursion".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from spaces for the next line of `*`'s on the current line of stars.

If you replace the spaces with a different character say '_' and print out 1 star you see this

```
___*__
__*_*__
_*_*_*__
__*_*__
___*__
___ <- look here
```

At the end there is some spaces being printed on the next line for the coming `*`. Quick fix is to check that there is a next star to print

```
public void results(int num) {
    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        System.out.print(space(num - i));
        System.out.println(method1(i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        System.out.println(method2(num - i));
        if(i+1 < num) // make sure we have another star
            System.out.print(space(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As David said, you should replace the piece of code with the following code :

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    int num = sc.nextInt();

    if (num < 0 || num > 25)

       System.out.println("Can not print")
       break;

    }else{

       new Pract2().results(num);


     }
```